# R - calling the min value of a factor

Tags: r

As part of the Coursera data specialization, I had to analyze the data sets on US hospitals and write a function with the following:

- Input: State names and causes (heart attack, heart failure or pneumonia)
- Output: the hospital with the least mortality rate of the given causes in the given state

The function should do the following:

- Load the dataset
- Check if the inputed state and causes (outcome) is valid
- Return the hospital with the least mortality rate, if there is a tie, return with alphabetical order

I was expecting to get the name of the hospital as a vector of length 1 of characters, but instead I got "character (0)" as output

Example of desired output:

```
best("TX", "pneumonia")
[1] "UNIVERSITY OF TEXAS HEALTH SCIENCE CENTER AT TYLER"
```

Example of real output:

```
best("TX", "pneumonia")
character(0)
```

Please help me look at where is wrong with my code. Many thankss

Here is my code:

```
## This function returns the best hospital in a state, given the disease types 
## based on its mortality rate in 30-day period

best <- function(state, outcome) {  
    ## calling data
    outcomedata <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", colClasses = "character")

    ## putting needed data into data frame
    outcomedf   <- as.data.frame(cbind(outcomedata[, 2],   outcomedata[, 7],   
                                 outcomedata[, 11],  outcomedata[, 17],  
                                 outcomedata[, 23]), 
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    colnames(outcomedf) <- c("hospital", "state", "heart attack", "heart failure", "pneumonia")

    ## Checking valid state
    if(!state %in% outcomedf[, "state"]){
        stop('invalid state') 

        ## Checking valid outcome 
    }
    else if(!outcome %in% c("heart attack", "heart failure", "pneumonia")){
        stop('invalid outcome') 

    ## Calling out best hospital  
    }
    else {
    ## Extracting data for given state
        obs_in_called_states <- which(outcomedf[, "state"] == state)
        obs_in_states_extract <- outcomedf[obs_in_called_states, ]
        oi <- as.numeric(obs_in_states_extract[, eval(outcome)])

        ## getting the min value
        minvalue <- min("oi", na.rm = TRUE)
        result  <- obs_in_states_extract[, "hospital"][which(oi == minvalue)]
        output  <- result[order(result)]
    }
    return(output)
}
```

Comment: I'm wondering whether you did [seach the internet first](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=nl&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20%5Br%5D%20cumsum%20diff%20increase#hl=nl&q=site:stackoverflow.com+%5Br%5D+best+function+state+outcome). There are lots of questions and answers on SO on how to solve this problem. Please read [ask]

Comment: Can you please simplify your question and focus only on the part that is causing you problem? Please simulate some data which shows your problem and present that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a data frame with names and scores e.g.

```
names <- c("name1","name2","name3")
scores <- c(1,3,4)

dataset1 <- data.frame(names,scores)
```

Find the minimum score only in column scores using:

```
min(dataset1$scores)
```

To find the corresponding vectors in another column (for example the names column) that have the minimum value, use:

```
paste(dataset1$names[dataset1$scores==min(dataset$scores)])
```

If you want to order the returns in alphabetical order, use the sort() function as:

```
paste(sort(dataset1$names[dataset1$scores==min(dataset1$scores)]))
```

NB this is not optimised for computational efficiency but rather was written for readability. There are many resources across SO for optimising your work.